# Split Project Pane in Atom editor

Tags: atom-editor

How can I split the Project pane? If I right click on the Project pane, and click Split right/left/up/down the pane is split but I can't add any files into that pane, I've tried to drag and drop some files but it isn't working.
For example, I have split the project panel into 3 parts as marked on the picture below, but the 2 and 3 are empty, how can I move files from 1 to 2 or 3 pane? Thanks.
[image]